# Are anthropomorphic features of Krishna referred to during the preaching of the Gita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

anthropomorphic =  "having human characteristics"

The Krishna before and after the Gita was of course a person with arms and legs and so forth and participated in the war as a charioteer and even almost took up arms.  There are theories that Bhagavad Gita is an interpolation:

https://www.bookgeeks.in/who-wrote-the-bhagavadgita-meghnad-desai-book-review/

If Krishna is only abstractly a person while the Gita was preached and nothing physical about him is described within the Gita, that would support the interpolation theory.  His inability to repeat it later when asked also suggests a discontinuity between Krishna the conductor of the war and Krishna of the Gita.

Comment: "His inability to repeat it later when asked also suggests a discontinuity between Krishna the conductor of the war and Krishna of the Gita." His so-called inability seems to more of an excuse to teach anugita, rather than repeat the same gita.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Krishna's body is described in many places in the Bhagavad Gita.  Chapter 1 of course describes him driving the chariot, but presumably you're asking about after that.  [Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4) is what he says in chapter 4:

> Although I am unborn and My transcendental body never deteriorates, and although I am the Lord of all living entities, I still appear in every millennium in My original transcendental form.

And [chapter 11](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11) describes his Vishwaroopam, but it also describes his four-armed form and his two-armed form:

> O universal form, O thousand-armed Lord, I wish to see You in Your four-armed form, with helmeted head and with club, wheel, conch and lotus ﬂower in Your hands. I long to see You in that form. The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: My dear Arjuna, happily have I shown you, by My internal potency, this supreme universal form within the material world. No one before you has ever seen this primal form, unlimited and full of glaring effulgence. O best of the Kuru warriors, no one before you has ever seen this universal form of Mine, for neither by studying the Vedas, nor by performing sacriﬁces, nor by charity, nor by pious activities, nor by severe penances can I be seen in this form in the material world. You have been perturbed and bewildered by seeing this horrible feature of Mine. Now let it be ﬁnished. My devotee, be free again from all disturbances. With a peaceful mind you can now see the form you desire. Sañjaya said to Dhṛtarāṣṭra: The Supreme Personality of Godhead, Kṛṣṇa, having spoken thus to Arjuna, displayed His real four-armed form and at last showed His two-armed form, thus encouraging the fearful Arjuna. When Arjuna thus saw Kṛṣṇa in His original form, he said: O Janārdana, seeing this humanlike form, so very beautiful, I am now composed in mind, and I am restored to my original nature.

Comment: Does avyayatma translate to transcendental body? @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: @AkshayS "avyaya — without deterioration" and "ātmā — body" as per [Vedabase](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/6).